# how to implement dependency between multiple tests run in parallel and the final test to be run in testNG?

Tags: testng

i have a requirement to move testNG results into results folder after all my tests are done. All my tests are run in parallel. This stops me from adding a separate test at the bottom of all my tests in testng.xml to copy the results...since that test will get run in parallel and not after all others tests are completed.

The current solution i have is to create 2 suites in a testng.xml file. One for running all my tests in parallel and the next for copying results.

Is this the right solution or a better way is available?

Currently my solution is the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<suite name="Suite 1">
<suite-files>
 <suite-file path="./SmokesQA.xml" />
 <suite-file path="./CopyResults.xml" />
 </suite-files>
</suite>
```

Comment: These results are custom results?  I would believe the reports generated by testng would be generated after all suites will be run, in which case the results would not even be there when the second suite runs.

Comment: ya these are custom...so any idea how to implement copying the results to another folder within testNG... BTW, thanks for pointing out the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through testng since the order of listeners is not gauranteed, it might be that the reports folder doesn't get generated by the time the listener runs.
So, I do not think testng is the right place to look for a solution.

Some other ways, I can think of, are to have a jenkins job which runs your tests and as a post build step executes a batch of copying to the folder.

Or a service which polls and copies the reports...

Comment: ya...i already have a shell script that checks if the results files have been modified in the last minute and then....copies them to my folder...it works for now... but i wanted to wrap this in testNG so as to keep all code within the framework....